# How to use debug in HP Load Runner?

Tags: loadrunner, debugging

Does any one know how to use debug in HP Load Runner?

It is possible to set break point, but there is no debug run mode (not in main menu, not in hot-buttons menu).

[image]

Here is quote from online documentation [How to Debug Scripts with Breakpoints](http://lrhelp.saas.hp.com/en/latest/help/WebHelp/Content/VuGen/105800_t_how_to_debug_scripts_breakpoints.htm):

> Run a script with breakpoints
>
> **Begin running the script as usual**. VuGen pauses script execution when
>   it reaches a breakpoint. You can examine the effects of the script run
>   up to the breakpoint, make any necessary changes, and then restart the
>   script from the breakpoint.
>
> To resume execution, select Replay > Run. Once restarted, the script
>   continues until it encounters another breakpoint or the end of the
>   script.

Does not work.

Comment: I use F10 key to step by step. I add variables to Watch window and also check in Runtime data pane. Is that what you are expecting in LR?

Answer (score 1):

Like you have pointed out, there is no debug mode in LoadRunner (as far as I recollect) like you would, in Eclipse IDE.

You will be able to place breakpoints on 'lr_' functions and when the script is run the execution will halt at the breakpoint. This can be used to verify, if the correlations and parameters substitution have occurred correctly up to the breakpoint.